# mysql how to do an inner join with a second inner join to the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one with notes

```
id, note, client#, flag, employee#, date
```

The other with employees

```
id, employee#
```

I want to find all the notes that have a "N" flag, but DO NOT have a "Y" flag for the same date and client#, but only for the employees that are in the employee table.

For example I start with:

```
1  mynote   123   Y   abc   1/1/2011
2  mynote   123   N   abc   1/1/2011
3  mynote   124   N   abc   1/1/2011
4  mynote   124   N   ccc   1/1/2011
```

(in my employees table I have employee abc)

so I started with:

```
SELECT * from notes a inner join employees b on a.employee = b.employee WHERE a.flag = 'N'
```

That works, I get what looks like a resonable list of notes for only the employees that are currently in the employees table (for example only abc - records 2 and 3 above).

Now, I need to get back only record 3 since it is an "N" record and has no matching "Y" record for the same date and client#.

I just cant seem to get the extra part figured out to add it on.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just remove the `flag` condition in your `WHERE` clause? Won't that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: I just clarified it a little, and I tried the queries below but they did not work, so I think my previous explanation was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a union for this. This way you can work with 2 different queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `flag =` expression to the `ON` clause, it becomes more simple:

```
SELECT * from employees e
inner join notes n1
on n1.employee = e.employee
  AND n1.flag = 'N'
inner join notes n2
ON n2.employee = e.employee
  AND n2.client = n1.client AND n2.date = n1.date AND n2.flag = 'Y'
```

I also borrowed the improved alias names from dasblinkenlight.